# Yii2: Make Dual axes hightchart using PHP array

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2

I want to create dual axes Highchart like as seen in image and i have install [miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts](https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts) extension.

[image]

My yii2 code

```
<?php
    use miloschuman\highcharts\Highcharts;

    $emp = ['zxc', 'sdf', 'fgh', 'ggg'];
    $totalData[] = ['name' => 'Total',  'type' => 'column', 'data' => [23,45,34,34]];
    $avgData[] = ['name' => 'Avarage', 'type' => 'spline', 'data' => [2.3,4.5,3.4,3.0]];
    echo Highcharts::widget([
            'options' => [  
                'chart'=>[
                    //'type'=>'column', 
                    'zoomType' => 'xy',
                ],
                'exporting'=>[
                    'enabled'=>false, 
                ],
                'credits'=>[
                        'enabled'=>false,
                ],
                'title'=>[
                    'text'=>Yii::t('comm', $model->fg_name),
                ],
                'subtitle'=>[
                    'text'=>'',
                    'margin'=>0,
                ],
                'xAxis'=>[
                    'type' => 'category',
                    'labels' => [
                        'rotation' => -45,
                        'style' => [
                            'fontSize' => '13px',
                            'fontFamily' => 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'categories'=> $emp,
                    'title'=>[
                        'text'=>'<b>'.Yii::t('comm', 'Employee').'</b>',
                    ],
                ],
                'yAxis'=>[
                    'title'=>[
                        'text'=>Yii::t('comm', 'TOTAL/AVARAGE'),
                    ],  
                ],
                'legend' => [
                    'enabled' => false
                ],
                'plotOptions'=>[
                     'column'=>[
                        'pointPadding'=>0.2,
                        'borderWidth'=>0
                     ],
                ],
                'series'=> [$avgData,$totalData]
                ],
        ]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [2amigos highcharts](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget), but I'm sure the process is the same, here is a recent sample I used to generate my dual axis chart:

```
'yAxis' => [ // primary axis
        [
          'title' => [
              'text' => 'Weeks'
          ],
          'tickInterval' => 5,
      ],
      [ // secondary axis
        'gridLineWidth' => 0,
        'title' => [
            'text' => '%'
        ],
        'max' => 100,
        'min' => 0,
        'opposite' => true,
      ]
    ],
```

My series ended up like this:

```
'series' => [$series,$line, $percent]
```

They were themselves arrays: Here is an example of one of the arrays, where you can state which axis the data belongs to, in my case and I guess yours `yAxis` will be 0 or 1. Change the `type` to whatever you like, this array was a column, but others wine splines

```
 $series Array
(
[name] => 90th Percentile
[type] => column
[yAxis] => 0
[tooltip] => Array
    (
        [valueSuffix] =>  Weeks
    )

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16.86
        [1] => 11.29
        [2] => 13.86
        [3] => 32.14
        [4] => 17.71
        [5] => 7.57
        [6] => 19
        [7] => 37.57
        [8] => 10.14
        [9] => 5.43
        [10] => 7.14
        [11] => 31.57
        [12] => 17.52
    )
```

)